# For linux, getting the total CPU time of a process and all it's sub processes that ever existsed

Tags: linux

So basically I have multiple users on my system and I want to determine how much CPU time they spend while being logged in into their shell and running different commands. I have a script which knows the PID of the shell they are logged in with. I must be able to probe the value regularly so I can't simply run the shell in time(1) or something like that.

I have glanced at /proc/$pid - anyone knows of a good value (or combination of values) there I could use? Maybe there's some kernel module for this?

An acceptable solution to my problem would allow querying init (the process with pid = 1) and find the total CPU time the entire system has used so far.

Comment: You just want to know how much CPU time they use or you want to limit it? Because resource quotas would help with the latter...

Comment: Do you want total CPU usage per user or for the whole system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using cgroups to throttle and control activity on a per-user basis to a per-cpu basis. Once that is done you can use the cgroups statistics patch to generate the information you are looking for.